# Does Cordova 1.9 work on iOS 6?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

Does Cordova 1.9 work on iOS 6?

I'll be working on it on Xcode 4.5.

I've already installed Cordova 2.0 and it is troublesome issues.

**CordovaLib**

**MainViewController.m**

**AppDelegate.m**

Should I downgrade to Phonegap / Cordova to 1.9 or upgrade to Cordova 2.1? Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

In my condition,I met many bugs when I building Apps by Cordova 1.9 on IOS6.

Even though we can run Cordova 1.9 on IOS6,but the plugins issue or other strange problems would make you tired.

So please upgrade it and face the truth.

Comment: Ahhh. I've upgraded it and you know what I've problems with Phonegap 2.0 and then 2.1 see a link, I'm none the wiser. You'll need a big dose of patient and understanding boss (If your're working) to upgrade to Phonegap 2.1...its littered with teething problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716830/xcode-4-5-no-such-file-or-directory-libcordova-a/12763460#comment17286768_12763460

Comment: Yes Phonegap 2.1 may make you crazy ... but phonegap 1.9 is old for ios6.

Comment: Can you explain "old" - phonegap 1.9 is old for ios6?

Comment: I guess it was supposed to be "_too_ old".

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to compile my app with iOS6 SDK with Cordova 1.9.

Make sure you remove armv7s from "Valid Architectures" in your app's "Build Settings". However, this means, you won't be able to target iPhone 5.

(Thanks to Apple, iPhone5 is not available for purchase yet in my country anyways!!, So I still have time to upgrade Cordova :) )

I am still waiting for Cordova 2.2 release. You can check [bug reports of Cordova](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/fixforversion/12322549#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3aversion-issues-panel) and decide for your own case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did managed to get Cordova 2.1 to work on my iphone. It is all about typing the right thing on Terminal.app to set up a project folder and armv7 armv7s in a correct place.

Comment: @Irishgirl>  Can you please put the specific right shell commands to get it to work?

Comment: I don't use Cordova 1.9. I use Cordova 2.1.