# libCordova.a stays in red, file not found

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I need some help here. I have wrastled with a phonegap/xcode build for days now and can´t figure it out.
The libCordova.a stays in red (file not found) and i can´t see why. So i gave up and setup a totally new project in xcode, using cordova 2.1.0 command line tools. But when i looked up the Projects folder I see that libCordova.a is again not to be found.

[Screenshot http://imageshack.us/a/img443/6529/bildschirmfoto20121024u.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img443/6529/bildschirmfoto20121024u.png)

Anyone here who has an idea how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You did not report about actual error messages appearing, so I'll assume you haven't tried building/running your app.

I've built a brand new Cordova project, too. Even though the libCordova.a appears red running the App works just fine. So my answer is you're not encountering an actual problem. Just hit the Run button and everything will be fine.

Please report back if this doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can test and build on device/simulator, but to archive and submit some errors may appear. Please check:

[libCordova.a file missing in PhoneGap 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401478/libcordova-a-file-missing-in-phonegap-2-9)

or

[Xcode 4.5 no such file or directory - libCordova.a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716830/xcode-4-5-no-such-file-or-directory-libcordova-a)