# Xcode 5 "No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, simulator

So all was well, in the process of uploading my app, when trying to archive app for upload, it brought several errors. So I was playing around with the architectures as directed by forums. However, suddenly the simulators wouldn't work either. This is the error message;

> Ld
>   /Users/ZEIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bored_of_Studies-cpzdzvafatzweibndcpsonriacio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bored\
>   of\ Studies.app/Bored\ of\ Studies normal i386
>       cd "/Users/ZEIN/Desktop/Xcode Components/IDZWebBrowser-Step3 2"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/ZEIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bored_of_Studies-cpzdzvafatzweibndcpsonriacio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/ZEIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bored_of_Studies-cpzdzvafatzweibndcpsonriacio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/ZEIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bored_of_Studies-cpzdzvafatzweibndcpsonriacio/Build/Intermediates/Bored\
>   of\ Studies.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bored\ of\
>   Studies.build/Objects-normal/i386/Bored\ of\ Studies.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 /Users/ZEIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bored_of_Studies-cpzdzvafatzweibndcpsonriacio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
>   -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework MessageUI -framework iAd -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ZEIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bored_of_Studies-cpzdzvafatzweibndcpsonriacio/Build/Intermediates/Bored\
>   of\ Studies.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bored\ of\
>   Studies.build/Objects-normal/i386/Bored\ of\
>   Studies_dependency_info.dat -o
>   /Users/ZEIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bored_of_Studies-cpzdzvafatzweibndcpsonriacio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bored\
>   of\ Studies.app/Bored\ of\ Studies
>
> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/ZEIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bored_of_Studies-cpzdzvafatzweibndcpsonriacio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a'

I'm freaking out because I have a deadline to publish this for a business, and this is a major set back. Also, my storyboard is 'red' in the build phases too! I'm worried I've lost my whole application which could not be recovered. Right now, my app is saved on my phone when it did successfully connect to my device.

I've tried literally everything from cleaning to changing the armv7, arm64, etc.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401478/libcordova-a-file-missing-in-phonegap-2-9

Comment: still the same error pops up!