# Apple Mach-O Linker error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, mach-o

I'm using `Xcode 5`. I can build and simulate my app, but when I archive my app I receive this eror:

> "Apple Mach-O linker Error Linker Command Failed with exit code 1."
>
> Ld
>   /Users/skyline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cityscape45-caolbyqfojifkfgusooirnhrplqi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/cityscape45/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/cityscape45.app/cityscape45
>   normal armv7
>       cd /Users/skyline/Desktop/cityscape
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/skyline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cityscape45-caolbyqfojifkfgusooirnhrplqi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/cityscape45/BuildProductsPath/Distribution-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/skyline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cityscape45-caolbyqfojifkfgusooirnhrplqi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/cityscape45/BuildProductsPath/Distribution-iphoneos
>   -filelist /Users/skyline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cityscape45-caolbyqfojifkfgusooirnhrplqi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/cityscape45/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/cityscape45.build/Distribution-iphoneos/cityscape45.build/Objects-normal/armv7/cityscape45.LinkFileList
>   -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -force_load /Users/skyline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cityscape45-caolbyqfojifkfgusooirnhrplqi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/cityscape45/BuildProductsPath/Distribution-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/skyline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cityscape45-caolbyqfojifkfgusooirnhrplqi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/cityscape45/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
>   /Users/skyline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cityscape45-caolbyqfojifkfgusooirnhrplqi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/cityscape45/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/cityscape45.build/Distribution-iphoneos/cityscape45.build/Objects-normal/armv7/cityscape45_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/skyline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cityscape45-caolbyqfojifkfgusooirnhrplqi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/cityscape45/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/cityscape45.app/cityscape45
>
> ld: file not found:
>   /Users/skyline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cityscape45-caolbyqfojifkfgusooirnhrplqi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/cityscape45/BuildProductsPath/Distribution-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the last line of the Linker Error description:

> ld: **file not found**: /Users/skyline/Library/.../**libCordova.a** clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

You may only see this error when archiving because an Archive build may use the *Release* build settings, as opposed to the *Debug* build settings.

Ensure that your library, `libCordova.a`, is properly linked in the build settings (specifically, "Other Linker Flags"). Also check your build phases to see if it is being copied with your product.

It looks like [this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401478/libcordova-a-file-missing-in-phonegap-2-9) should provide a solution for you. This [SO post may also be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716830/xcode-4-5-no-such-file-or-directory-libcordova-a). If those don't help, a quick google search for "ld file not found Xcode 5" turns up lots of results.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by first building the CordovaLib project separately from within XCode and then building my project.